# How to use initializer_list list to initialize a map with customized class

Tags: c++, initializer-list, explicit

The following code can work:

```
pair<int, string> p({1, "aaa"});
```

However, the following code can't work:

```
struct XXX {
  XXX() {}
  explicit XXX(int l) : v(l) {}
  int v = 1;
};
pair<int, XXX> p2({1, 2});
```

I understand that if I remove the "explicit", the code can work. However, using explicit has its benefits... How to make the initializer_list work with explicit keyword is used..?

Comment: By explicitly constructing an instance of your class?

Comment: `initializer_list` is an argument for the `pair` constructor which can't be edited or overloaded.

Comment: The construction of an `XXX` from the `1` inside the initialiser list is implicit. You're asking how to allow an `explicit` constructor to be used implicitly? You can't, that's the whole point of `explicit`. I really hope I'm misunderstanding what you're asking, and if so, that you'll take this opportunity to explain what you *do* want to know.

Comment: You cannot initialize member variable `v` in the class declaration, unless it is static. And when it was static, you could not initialize it in the constructor on the line before.

Answer (score 3):

```
pair<int, XXX> p2({1, XXX(2)});
```